Strange squares appear during rendering, It's likely from the compositing but I'd like to keep the effects if possible


I'm working on a project and it's complete, but during rendering these strange square miscolored artifacts showed up randomly around the screen and appeared in the final images.

Can you share your Blender project file? Instructions for sharing.

https://small.fileditchstuff.me/s12/sLfqXkbZIEQzFGzsKdBo.blend
here it is.
